# How to add section and values to ini using configparser in Python?

Tags: python, configparser

I would like to ask why the ini file created using my code is empty.
I intend to create an ini file on the same directory as that of the py file.
So far, the ini is generated but it is empty.

```
import os
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser

#directory of folder
testdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
#file directory
newdir = testdir + "\\test99.ini"

#config ini
config.add_section('testdata')
config.add_section('testdata2')
config.set('testdata','val', '200')
config.set('testdata2','val', '300')

#write ini
newini = open(newdir, 'w')
config.write(newini)
newini.close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some parenthesis and importing the wrong things. Consult [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html).

```
import os
import configparser

config = configparser.RawConfigParser()

#directory of folder
testdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
#file directory
newdir = testdir + "/test.ini"

#config ini
config.add_section('testdata')
config.add_section('testdata2')
config.set('testdata','val', '200')
config.set('testdata2','val', '300')

#write ini
with open(newdir, 'w') as newini:
    config.write(newini)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import ConfigParser  # spelling mistake, 

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()  # need create an object first

#directory of folder
testdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
#file directory
newdir = os.path.join(testdir,"test99.ini") # use os.path.join to concat filepath.

#config ini
config.add_section('testdata')
config.add_section('testdata2')
config.set('testdata','val', '200')
config.set('testdata2','val', '300')

#write ini
newini = open(newdir, 'w')
config.write(newini)
newini.close
```

Comment: I cannot find the ConfigParser. It seems the problem is due to a missing parenthesis when creating an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
```

should be

```
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
```

everything else works perfectly